# Yii2 - simplify multiple similar url rules

Tags: yii2

I have quite a few actions in my SiteController. I don't want `site` in the URL, so I have this in my config file:

```
'rules' => [
    '/' => 'site/index',
    'about' => 'site/about',
    'contact' => 'site/contact',
    'login' => 'site/login',
    'logout' => 'site/logout',
    'register' => 'site/register',
],
```

Is there a way to simplify all of this (excluding the `/` route) in to one rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way:

```
'<action:(about|contact|login|logout|register)>' => 'site/<action>',
```

The answer posted by Shringiraj Dewangan will match *any* request and route to site controller, whereas this will only match the specified requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
'rules' => [
    '<action:\w+>' => 'site/<action>',
],
```